# Scala merge list of maps

Tags: scala, generics, scala-collections

Input =

```
val data = List(
    Map("id" -> "123", "name" -> "raju", 
        "sub" -> List(Map("id" -> "english", "status" -> 2))), 
    Map("id" -> "123", "name" -> "raju", 
        "sub" -> List(Map("id" -> "english", "status" -> 0), 
                      Map("id" -> "hindi", "status" -> 0))))
```

Expected Output:

```
val data = List(
    Map("id" -> "123", "name" -> "raju",
        "sub" -> List(Map("id" -> "english", "status" -> 2),
                      Map("id" -> "hindi", "status" -> 1),
                      Map("id" -> "english", "status" -> 0),
                      Map("id" -> "hindi", "status" -> 0))))
```

I'm trying to merge the "sub" key values into a list without removing the old keys but I couldn't able to get it. can anyone please help with this using scala.

Comment: Why don't you create proper classes with properties, instead of trying to do this with lists of maps? Your code will get much more readable if you model your domain correctly.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you are doing? Where does `"status" -> 1` come from? Why `1`?

Comment: Also, what is the logic for the merge here? Why is "hindi" suddenly getting a status of 1 after the merge?

Comment: The reason I'm merging this  I usually get a duplicate same "id" and "name" events with different "sub" values all together

Comment: I get all those events from the kafaka

Comment: any workaround? @marstran

Comment: Workaround for what?

Comment: I think you're dealing with your problem the wrong way. You're using Scala, but it looks like you're trying to mimic Javascript. Start by creating some classes to represent each concept, then the problem will definitely be simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by creating some case classes. It is much easier to work with these than with maps.

```
case class Person(id: String, name: String, sub: List[Language]) 

case class Language(id: String, status: Int)
```

Now, create a list of `Person`:

```
val data = List(
    Person("123", "raju", List(Language("english", 2))),
    Person("123", "raju", List(Language("english", 0), Language("hindi", 0))))
```

I don't know what your merging logic is, but let's say you just want to concatenate the `sub`-lists for persons with the same ID. You could do it this way:

```
// Gets a map from ID to the list of persons with that ID
data.groupBy(_.id)

// Gets a List[List[Person]] (the values of the map)
.values

// Makes a new Person out of the inner list of persons, concatenating all the languages of that person.
.map(persons => Person(
    persons.head.id,
    persons.head.name, 
    persons.flatMap(_.sub)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is example that works on pure Maps/Lists like in your example.

```scala
val data = List(
    Map("id" -> "123", "name" -> "raju", 
        "sub" -> List(Map("id" -> "english", "status" -> 2))), 
    Map("id" -> "123", "name" -> "raju", 
        "sub" -> List(Map("id" -> "english", "status" -> 0), 
                      Map("id" -> "hindi", "status" -> 0))))
                      
val expected = List(
    Map("id" -> "123", "name" -> "raju",
        "sub" -> List(Map("id" -> "english", "status" -> 2),
                      Map("id" -> "hindi", "status" -> 1),
                      Map("id" -> "english", "status" -> 0),
                      Map("id" -> "hindi", "status" -> 0))))
                      
val res = data.groupBy(x => (x.get("id"), x.get("name"))).collect { case (_, items) => 
  items.reduceLeft { (l, r) =>
    l.updated("sub", l("sub").asInstanceOf[List[_]] ++ r("sub").asInstanceOf[List[_]])
  }
}

println(res)
```

https://scalafiddle.io/sf/FBj4Mvi/0

PS: To be honest creating typed structure (as proposed by others) is probably still better sollution.